# Prove that the characteristic polynomial of any $g\in G$, where $G$ is a finite subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb Q)$, has integer coefficients.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a finite subgroup of the group of invertible $n\times n$ rational matrices. Show that the characteristic polynomial of any $g\in G$ has integer coefficients.

---

My attempt:

Suppose the order of group $G$ is $n$, then for every $g\in G\leqslant GL(n,\mathbb Q)$, we have $g^n=I$, the identity matrix. Hence the minimal polynomial $m(x)\in\mathbb Q[x]$ of $g$ divides $x^n-1$.

If $n=1$ or $n=2$, then by trivial verification, we know that the characteristic polynomial of any $g$ has integer coefficients.

What about other situations? Indeed, we claim that $m(x)|(x^n-1)$ but there are many possibilities for $m(x)$. Any help?

Comment: Hint: [Gauss's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the symbol $n$ for two different numbers, which may lead to some confusion and/or misunderstanding. I'll denote the order of $G$ by $k$ instead.

That the minimial polynomial $m(x)\in\Bbb{Q}[x]$ of $g$ has integer coefficients follows immediately from Gauss's lemma: Because $m(x)$ divides $x^k-1$ we have
$$x^k-1=m(x)q(x),$$
for some $q(x)\in\Bbb{Q}[x]$. Because $x^k-1$ and $m(x)$ are monic, also $q(x)$ is monic and so Gauss's lemma tells us that $m(x),q(x)\in\Bbb{Z}[x]$.

---

As there are many variations of Gauss's lemma, let me clarify what I mean by Gauss's lemma:

> If $g_1,g_2\in\Bbb{Q}[x]$ are monic and such that $g_1g_2\in\Bbb{Z}[x]$, then $g_1,g_2\in\Bbb{Z}[x]$.

The proof is simple, and relies solely on the fact that the product of two primitive polynomials is again primitive. (A polynomial with integer coefficients is called *primitive* if the greatest common divisor of its coefficients is $1$)

*Proof.* Let $c_1$ and $c_2$ denote the least common multiples of the denominators of the coefficients of $g_1$ and $g_2$, respectively. Then $c_1g_1,c_2g_2\in\Bbb{Z}[x]$ and both are primitive, and so their product is also primitive, which is
$$(c_1g_1)(c_2g_2)=c_1c_2g_1g_2\in\Bbb{Z}[x],$$
where $g_1g_2\in\Bbb{Z}[x]$. Therefore $c_1c_2=\pm1$, which implies $c_1,c_2=\pm1$ and hence $g_1,g_2\in\Bbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: I think we can not conclude that $m(x)\in\mathbb Z[x]$, this should be a premise. Gauss's lemma only tells us that $x^k-1$ is reducible in $\mathbb Z[x]$. Only when $m(x)\in\mathbb Z[x]$ is primitive, $m(x)|(x^k-1)$ in $\mathbb Q[x]$ implies $m(x)|(x^k-1)$ in $\mathbb Z[x]$. In fact, we can require $m(x)$ to be primitive and lying in $\mathbb Z[x]$ by clearing out denominators. Consequently, note that the leading term of $x^k-1$ is $1$, we have $m(x)$ is a monic polynomial in $\mathbb Z[x]$.

Comment: @Bach Let me expand my answer, as there are many variations of Gauss's lemma.